# GoogleSignInAccount#zzmL() does what?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-signin

I've been doing **SignIn using Google** in my Android project and i came up with a method named `GoogleSignInAccount#zzmL()`. It returns a unique string, something like `08D09E346FF478C3A407B37B90A8224E`, after successful signin.

So, here are my questions...

- What is that string ?
- Would it change in future ? or is it like the unique id for an account which may not change in future.
- Why the method
  named `zzmL`? (there are other similar methods named  like
  `zzmI,zzmM` in the same class)

I googled a lot for the documentation of these methods, but i couldn't find one.

Am i asking a wrong question ? :/

If you need any clarification , ask me in the comments.

Comment: if you don't know what that method does then you wont 't need it. It's an obfuscated method and probably you shouldn't be relying on it.

Comment: @MarkC. Because am just curious. :)

Comment: @PedroOliveira : I need to get a permanent unique id other than the normal account id for the signed in account. so, the method named `zzmL` does return a unique string, I want to know HOW UNIQUE is that!

Comment: That's something new to me too and in the same way, I got curious too. Can you please share your references? :)

Comment: @Teyam: :) , Ofcrs. but i got no information about these methods. :(